# How to copy the error message when vim start?

Tags: vim

If I press any key, the message will disappear.
I already know use `: message` to show the error message but I can't copy it to my register or print it to the .txt file.
I have read the help message, googled the question.

Answer (score 4):

The last error message should be available in a builtin variable named `v:errmsg` and the last status message is in `v:statusmsg`.

There's also `:h execute()` function which runs any VimScript command and returns its output.

Here's a generic mapping with redirection to the current buffer:

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>x :put =trim(execute(input(':', '', 'command')))<CR>
```

Press `<leader>x`, then enter your command, such as `5mess` and press `<Enter>`. The last five message lines will be added to the current buffer.

Comment: Thanks very much ! Helps me  a lot. Knowning this a can make me go on much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

it's easier to resolve by starting  vim with `--log` option to logging to file

```
vim --log /tmp/vim.log
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy the error msg I found this useful:

`let @* = execute('messages')`

That will copy to the clipboard.

Another option is to write it on the buffer:

`:put =execute('messages')`

From this post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31067/copy-vim-messages-into-clipboard